# initiateAnalysisExport () Method with OBIEE web services not returning queryID

Tags: java, web-services, oracle12c, obiee

I'm trying to use the webservices API in OBIEE with the initiateAnalysisExport() method of the AnalysisExportViews service in OBIEE 12C. I can send the API request without any issues, but the completeAnalysisExport and queryID fields in the AnalysisExportResult structure aren't returning anything. However, the viewData and mimeType fields are properly populated.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here. I need the queryID for the completeAnalysisExport method to obtain the export file. I've also noticed that the documentation for queryID is empty: https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1221/biee/BIEIT/structures.htm#BIEIT6968.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like the same as https://forums.oracle.com/ords/apexds/post/initiateanalysisexport-method-with-obiee-web-services-not-r-8913, the answer is posted there.

TL;DR: by default it does execute in a synchronous mode and therefore there is no need for the queryID. More details in the Oracle Forum.